# Refresh ListView c#

Tags: c#, listview

Bom dia. 
Tenho um Form1 com vários métodos. Num dos métodos crio outro form2. No Form1, tenho um listView com valores da Base de dados. No form2 vou inserir novos valores. Queria que no form1, me atualizasse o ListView, mas não estou a conseguir. Já coloquei this.refresh();

Muito obrigada

Comment: Melhore a pergunta para ter mais chances de resposta. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há várias formas de implementar essa situação, você poderia descrever melhor sua situação para ajudarmos com a melhor forma para seu caso.

Considerando que você irá bloquear o form1 enquanto o form2 estiver aberto, e ao "gravar" no form2, ele fecha, retornando para o form1, pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

1- No evento onde abre o form2, utilize o ShowDialog e caso retorne OK, você busca os dados novamente para o listView. No form2, ao final do evento "Gravar" informe: "this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;"

Código do Form1:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void AtualizaListView()
    {
        //Vai no banco de dados, e atualiza o listview

    }

    private void buttonInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        if ( form.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            AtualizaListView();
        }
    }
```

Código Form2:

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Grava no banco de dados

            //Se tudo estiver correto, 
            this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Agora, se você precisa manter o Form2 aberto, e ainda assim atualizar o Form1, no Form1 declare o método de busca no banco de dados como publico, e passe o objeto do Form1 como parâmetro ao Form2. No Gravar do Form2, execute o método de busca no banco de dados presente no Form1. Exemplo de Código:

Form1:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void AtualizaListView()
    {
        //Vai no banco de dados, e atualiza o listview

    }

    private void buttonInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.form1 = this;
        form.Show();
    }
```

Form2:

```
    public Form1 form1 { get; set; }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Grava no banco de dados

            //Se tudo estiver correto, 

            form1.AtualizaListView();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muito Obriagada @Rovann, ajudou imenso :)

Comment: disponha =] ... =]

Answer (score 1):

Fiz de outra forma. 
Limpei o ListView e depois voltei a preenchê-lo!
Assim :

```
listView.Items.Clear();
Search();
```

O search() é onde me vai buscar os valores para fazer o preenchimento com os dados para o ListView.